# Where is the terminal application on the filesystem?

Tags: terminal

I want to be able to launch a Terminal window using [JiTouch](http://www.jitouch.com/), which allows me to make a gesture open a file, so I want to know the location of the Terminal app so that I can open it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is this all you want?

`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`

Comment: Yeh, that is it. I just retried searching with spotlight and saw that it was actually finding it - it was just down the bottom!

Comment: A little bit of Spotlight cleverness allows you learn where an  item is by Cmd-clicking or Cmd-<return>ing its entry in the Spotlight list.  Instead of launching the item, it will open a finder window to the item's parent folder with the item highlighted.  Besides showing you where that item resides, it lets you do lots of things to it - delete it, move it, or open it with a non-default application.  My favorite, for a PDF or a spreadsheet, is to just touch <space> to open it with QuickView.

Comment: Or just hold the ⌘ key – try it! (:

Answer (score 9):

In macOS 10.15 Catalina, I found it in:

`/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`

This is how I found it:

1. open *Spotlight* (`Cmd+Space`)
2. type: *Terminal* (typing the full name ensures it's the first search result at the top)
3. if not already selected, select (single-click) the *Terminal.app* found by Spotlight (should the first one in the list), after the app is selected, press the `Cmd` key, while holding that key the full path will be shown in the bottom-right corner of *Spotlight*
4. alternatively continue with the following steps: hold the `Cmd` key, then hit the `Enter` key or double-click on the *Terminal.app* found by Spotlight
5. that will open *Finder* and highlight *Terminal.app*
6. if you drag *Terminal.app* into a text file, another terminal, or even a browser URL bar, it will show you the full path

(Funny enough, if you right-click and choose *Get Info*, it will show you as if it's actually just in */Applications/Utilities*, e.g. without */System*).

The difference between the two paths is significant when used in a shell or (I assume) programmatically, for example:

```
~ % file /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app: cannot open '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app' (No such file or directory)
~ %
~ % file /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app: directory
```

Comment: This is, strictly speaking, the correct answer - however the shorter form refers to this location so the difference is inconsequential for the purpose of locating the application.

Comment: It's not inconsequential in certain cases (which seem to apply to the OP), see latest edit I just did.